How to use event-delegation properly instead of adding a 2nd, concurring, event-listener for the same event-type?
I am using a document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
to force the input pattern (first must be a letter, then prevent consecutive spaces, etc.)
Now I want to make a 2nd document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () for an email.
(I want to prevent multiple .'s and prevent more than 1 @)
Here is my code for both of the above but it isn't working, it only capitalizes the email (i kept that option on to see if that part works, which it does but nothing else does work.)
Here is the first part (I also tried something else, removing the first }); at the document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()  at the start of the 2nd as I heard that should work but that didn't work either.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Function to handle all keypress events
  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    const input = event.target;
    const char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

    // Prevent first character from being a space
    if (input.selectionStart === 0 && event.code === "Space") {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    // Prevent first character from being a non-letter
    if (input.selectionStart === 0 && !/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    // Prevent consecutive spaces
    const lastChar = input.value.charAt(input.selectionStart - 1);
    if (char === " " && lastChar === " ") {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }

  // Attach event listeners to input fields
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='real_name'], input[name='display_name']");
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);

    // Set text-transform to capitalize to force capitalization of each word
    input.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
  });
});
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Function to handle all keypress events
  function handleKeyPress2(event) {
    const input = event.target;
    const char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

    // Prevent first character from being a space
    if (input.selectionStart === 0 && event.code === "Space") {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    // Prevent consecutive spaces
    const lastChar = input.value.charAt(input.selectionStart - 1);
    if (char === "@" && lastChar === "@") {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || event.which;
    if (key == 32) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return key;
    }
  }

  // Attach event listeners to input fields
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='email']");
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress2);

    // Set text-transform to capitalize to force capitalization of each word
    input.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
  });
});




Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add relevant HTML, CSS and frameworks you use from CDN

The issue is probably not with binding to the DOMContentLoaded event twice, but rather that you are binding to the keypress twice for all those fields - and I'm guessing that combination of event.preventDefault(); and return; likely prevents it from even executing the second assigned keypress handler. You should rather try to do all those things in one keypress handler to begin with.


You don't need multiple DOMContentLoaded handlers. You can put all your logic within a single one. 2) Is the email field a type="email"? This has a slightly different key-based event model to a type="text" element, which may account for the issue you have. 3) Do not use text-transform on an input element. It does not accurately reflect what the user has entered in to the form and may cause confusion. For example, they enter foo but see Foo, and your server will still receive foo, so any checks for validity/comparison will be affected.


I couldn't reproduce the issue, It worked fine. Please add the HTML file. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Also you definitely need to look at Event Delegation. Have ONE event handler on the nearest static container for the inputs


idk how to put it all together. 2. type="email" 3. no text-transform


First, one does not even necessarily need a 'DOMContentLoaded' handler for dealing with input-element related 'keypress' events, as long as the element-query for the latter's registration starts after the targeted element/s have been made accessible within the DOM.
Second, and regardless of whether one registers the event-handling at 'DOMContentLoaded', one always should make use of event-delegation in order to handle input-element related 'keypress' events.
One would register the event-listener at the closest available parent of all involved input-elements. The main-handler then just needs to validate and distinguish the relevant input-elements in order to forward the element-type/element-name specific handling to the targeted element's related, more specialized, handler function.
Edit
The above described, and beneath implemented approach (event-delegation) achieves exactly what the OP just recently did ask for in one of the comments ...

"How can I make 2 separate systems? One to watch and modify changes to the names, and another to work separately with the email?"
Antarctica-UFO // Commented 1 hour ago



function handleNameFieldKeypress(target, evt) {
  console.log('handleNameFieldKeypress ... target ...', target);

  const char = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);

  const { selectionStart } = target;

  const isNotValid = (selectionStart === 0 && (

    evt.code === 'Space' ||
    !/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char)

  )) || (

    char === ' ' &&
    target.value.charAt(selectionStart - 1) === ' '
  );
  if (isNotValid) {

    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
function handleEmailFieldKeypress(target, evt) {
  console.log('handleEmailFieldKeypress ... target ...', target);

  const { selectionStart } = target;

  const isNotValid =
    (selectionStart === 0 && evt.code === 'Space') || (

      String.fromCharCode(evt.which) === '@' &&
      target.value.charAt(selectionStart - 1) === '@'
    );

  if (isNotValid) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    return;
  }
  const key = evt.keyCode || evt.charCode || evt.which;

  return (key !== 32) && key;
}

function handleInputFieldKeypress(evt) {
  const { target } = evt;

  let result;

  if (target.matches('input[name="real_name"], input[name="display_name"]')) {

    result = handleNameFieldKeypress(target, evt);

  } else if (target.matches('input[name="email"]')) {

    result = handleEmailFieldKeypress(target, evt);
  }
  return result;
}

document
  .addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    document
      .querySelector('form')
      .addEventListener('keypress', handleInputFieldKeypress);
  });
body { margin: 0; }
form { width: 32%; }
fieldset { margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
label, label > span { display: block; }
label > span { margin: 4px 0 2px 0; }
/*
input[name="email"],
input[name="real_name"],
input[name="display_name"] { text-transform: capitalize; }
*/
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 66%; min-height: 100%; }
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>User Data</legend>
  
    <label>
      <span>Real Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="real_name" />
    </label>
  
    <label>
      <span>Display Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="display_name" />
    </label>

  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  
    <label>
      <span>E-mail Address</span>
      <input type="email" name="email" />
    </label>

  </fieldset>
</form>

<!--
<script>

// - one does not even need a 'DOMContentLoaded' event listener
//   for dealing with input-element related 'keypress' events,
//   as long as the element-query starts after the targeted
//   element/s have been made accessible within the DOM.

function handleNameFieldKeypress(target, evt) {
  console.log('handleNameFieldKeypress ... target ...', target);

  const char = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);

  const { selectionStart } = target;

  const isNotValid = (selectionStart === 0 && (

    evt.code === 'Space' ||
    !/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char)

  )) || (

    char === ' ' &&
    target.value.charAt(selectionStart - 1) === ' '
  );
  if (isNotValid) {

    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
function handleEmailFieldKeypress(target, evt) {
  console.log('handleEmailFieldKeypress ... target ...', target);

  const { selectionStart } = target;

  const isNotValid =
    (selectionStart === 0 && evt.code === 'Space') || (

      String.fromCharCode(evt.which) === '@' &&
      target.value.charAt(selectionStart - 1) === '@'
    );

  if (isNotValid) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    return;
  }
  const key = evt.keyCode || evt.charCode || evt.which;

  return (key !== 32) && key;
}

function handleInputFieldKeypress(evt) {
  const { target } = evt;

  let result;

  if (target.matches('input[name="real_name"], input[name="display_name"]')) {

    result = handleNameFieldKeypress(target, evt);

  } else if (target.matches('input[name="email"]')) {

    result = handleEmailFieldKeypress(target, evt);
  }
  return result;
}
document
  .querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('keypress', handleInputFieldKeypress);

</script>
//-->




@Antarctica-UFO ... check out my above answer. It's approach and implementation achieve exactly what you did ask an hour ago in one of your comments ... "How can I make 2 separate systems? One to watch and modify changes to the names, and another to work separately with the email?" Antarctica-UFO

Wow thanks! I only need 2 more things out of this now! How to allow only 1 single @ in the entire email. And to force names to start with 1 capital letter followed by all small case letters, special characters or numbers in that word (a 2nd word in the name follow the same rules with the first letter being capitalized...). After this, I'm all done with all my forms :) Thanks again Peter Seliger, you are a genius!

What you're asking in addition is another task (or two) and not related to the problem you've described in this thread. Since you've got provided the approach that handles what you've ask for, everything else needs to be described and boiled down into an example in yet another thread. I'm not unwilling to provide a solution when requirements within a thread do change or add up. I almost always provide help immediately. But I'm on vacation now. No coding for SO within the next weeks.

You do not need to attach multiple DOMContentLoaded event handlers. You can bind a single one and put all the event handlers for your HTML elements within that.
The cause of your issue, however, is because you're using the keydown event on an input of type="email". This has some inconsistent behaviour with type="text" inputs, as you've discovered.
Given your goal, the simplest approach would be to use the built-in HTML validators as this will ensure all fields are given a value on submission, and also ensure the email field is of the correct format. This has the additional benefit of working whether or not the user has Javascript enabled in their browser.
Here's a working example:


function nameInputRestrictor(event) {
  const input = event.target;
  const char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

  // Prevent first character from being a space
  if (input.selectionStart === 0 && event.code === "Space") {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  // Prevent first character from being a non-letter
  if (input.selectionStart === 0 && !/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  // Prevent consecutive spaces
  const lastChar = input.value.charAt(input.selectionStart - 1);
  if (char === " " && lastChar === " ") {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("input[name='real_name'], input[name='display_name']").forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("keypress", nameInputRestrictor);
  });
});
label {
  display: block;
} 
<form>
  <label>
    Real name: <input type="text" name="real_name" required />
  </label>
  <label>
    Display name: <input type="text" name="display_name" required />
  </label>
  <label>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" required />
  </label>
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



Also note that using text-transform on an input element is extremely bad practice. This is because the field will then not exactly match what the user has typed in. For example, they may think that they typed in Foo, but they actually entered foo, and your server-side logic will receive foo when the form is submit, which is not what the user believed they provided to you.

How can I make 2 separate systems? One to watch and modify changes to the names, and another to work separately with the email?

Add the event listener to it separately, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/217fucLs/. As I mentioned above, you shouldn't need to do this when using the HTML validators, though.

That doesn't show how to make 2 separate systems. The email doesn't do anything. Where do you put the codes for the email?

I thought that was obvious - you put it where I wrote 'handle email input here...'

it's not the same. I tried adding something like you did for the names but it doesn't fit in there, I am getting red ' and )'s in Visual Studio Code (unless Something else has to go in there).... can you add something in there like how to prevent more than 1 @ and consecutive .'s so I can see how please?

Then you've done it wrong. I'd suggest starting a new question about this if you're struggling, although to be honest it's very basic JS syntax. Perhaps lookup some tutorials

Thanks for the help, but posting the same question again without any changes would not do me any good. I guess I will hire someone for some code.
